# sbt throws [error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

- I cleaned my `~/.ivy2/cache` directory.
- My `project/plugins.sbt` file :

```sh
$ cat project/plugins.sbt
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn
// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.10")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.2.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.3.2")
```

- My My `~/.sbt/repositories` file :

```sh
$ cat ~/.sbt/repositories
[repositories]
  local
  activator-launcher-local: file://${activator.local.repository-${activator.home-${user.home}/.activator}/repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  activator-local: file://${activator.local.repository-/Users/debodirno/activator-dist-1.3.12/repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-releases-repo: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
  typesafe-releases: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases
  typesafe-ivy-releasez: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

I am running `activator clean`:

```sh
$ activator clean
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/debodirno/personal/src/sitesearch/project
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.iq80.leveldb/leveldb/0.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.iq80.leveldb/leveldb/0.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.iq80.leveldb/leveldb-api/0.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.iq80.leveldb/leveldb-api/0.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-all/1.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-all/1.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni/1.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni/1.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.hawtjni/hawtjni-runtime/1.8/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.fusesource.hawtjni/hawtjni-runtime/1.8/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-osx/1.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-osx/1.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-linux32/1.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-linux32/1.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-linux64/1.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-linux64/1.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused (Connection refused) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-win32/1.5/ivys/ivy.xml
...
...
...
```

Basically, I want to know from where is it getting the http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/
Also, I have not changed configurations of my project, so why is this failing suddenly.

Comment: I have similar errors since yesterday:

[error]         Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.apache#apache;14 {}:: 
[error]         Typesafe repository: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;14: res=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/apache/apache/14/apache-14.jar: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.typesafe.com/34.193.5.230:80
[error]         Typesafe repository: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;14: res=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/apache/apache/14/apache-14.pom: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Able to resolve after adding additional type safe https resolver to the build.sbt. By default sbt was picking the http one. If you already have resolver configured (like I have maven) the new line is important or else you can use Seq construct)

resolvers += "Maven Central Server" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

resolvers += "Typesafe Server" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"

Comment: Not able to resolve this even after this change

Answer (score 5):

I had my resolvers set to "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/" and changing the resolver to using https made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Need to upgrade the sbt.version as mentioned in the link below, if the issue still persists

In `build.properties` file

`sbt.version=0.13.18`

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6200